# How to get IPN for payout using sandbox.paypal

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, openerp-7, odoo-8

I am working on payment through Paypal and I am not able to get IPN  and I make research on it and there is no option of IPN settings **Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification.** 
I have also tried [Dynamically Setting the Notification URL](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#id089EG030E5Z) for sandbox.paypal but failed.

How can I get the IPN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of accounts in sandbox.paypal

1. personal
2. business

We can get IPN if account type is Business.
I was looking for IPN while my account type was personal.
I checked it for Business account type and got IPN for payouts.

Path is : **Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification**